# Power for 24VDC 5A Motor

Tags: power-supply

I have a 24 VDC 5A motor. I wish to power it with two 12V motorcycle batteries in series for about one hour. Can I hook the batteries up directly or will I fry the motor? Does the CCA of the batteries matter?  What gauge cable should I use between the batteries?

I have not acquired the batteries yet. I'm looking for guidance.  The max distance between batteries and motor 2ft max. I do not know the amps under load for the motor. It has a 5A rating on the motor.

Comment: The amp-hour rating of the batteries is more important than the CCA.  (In fact, the CCA rating is pretty much meaningless for this application.)  In theory, a first approximation of the "run time" would be the amp-hour rating divided by 5A.  (Note that you would not add the two amp-hour ratings together, but rather use the lowest of the two, if they are not identical.)

Comment: If the batteries are both 5AH you will drain them completely in an hour. As motorcycle batteries aren't usually deep discharge batteries, this would be bad. So choose batteries rated at 10AH or more and you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

How much current does your motor draw under load?

What size are your batteries?

How much distance between the batteries and the motor?

You can power your 24V motor from 2- 12V batteries in series but the rest of your questions depend on the answers to my questions.